# Selecting the "System Font" for an Attributed String through the Interface Builder

Tags: ios, fonts, xcode8

I am trying to select the "system font" for my labels in the Interface Builder. All of these labels contain attributed string. If they were "pain labels" I could just easily select the "system font" and my app would automatically use "Helvetica" for iOS 8 and "San Francisco" for iOS 9+.

The problem is that this doesn't seem possible when using attributed strings. (I need them for the spacing between lines).

Even if I were to download the fonts and select one in the interface builder it wouldn't automatically change depending on the iOS just as the "plain text" labels do.

Is there a way to accomplish this? Maybe I'm missing something.

By the way, my current work around is to connect all the labels to an outlet array and loop through them creating NSMutableAttributedString, then just "overriding" the font property with the programmatically retrieved system font.

The drawback of this is that the labels are created twice so it's slower on screens with a lot of labels.

Edit: The code that I use to "change" the font:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    for label in labelsToFormat {
        let targetFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: label.font.pointSize)
        let originalLabel = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: label.attributedText!)
        originalLabel.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: targetFont, range: NSMakeRange(0, originalLabel.length))
        label.attributedText = originalLabel
    }

    for label in labelsToFormatBold {
        let targetFont = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: label.font.pointSize)
        let originalLabel = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: label.attributedText!)
        originalLabel.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: targetFont, range: NSMakeRange(0, originalLabel.length))
        label.attributedText = originalLabel
    }
}
```

Comment: "If they were play labels" What is a "play label"?

Comment: @matt sorry, misspell, I meant "plain labels". As in the ones that are automatically set by default.

Comment: I think what you're going is basically right. Using NSFontDescriptor, you can derive the styled font (e.g. italic or bold) from the system font programmatically.

Comment: I didn't know about font descriptor, i'm gonna check that. But I was hoping for a way to do it through the interface builder, since using the system font is quite a common task, i'd think there is a way to actually select it as well when using attributed strings. At the very least I wonder if it's possible to create a sub class that automatically overrides the label initialization process so that it's automatically set to the system font before initialization, thus avoiding creating the label once with the wrong font and resetting it after with code (which is why theres a slow down).

Comment: The notion that there's a "slow down" suggests to me that something is wrong with your code. But you have not shown it, so who knows?

Comment: lol sorry, I hadn't added the code before because i was hoping for an IB solution. But code wise it doesn't do anything special. Doesn't the slow down come from the label's content being created twice? Once when loaded from the interface builder init with coder, and then in my view controller's view did load where i change the font.

Comment: I'm surprised that such innocent looking code could create a perceptible "slowdown". What you're doing is just the sort of thing I would have done. Can you use Instruments to find out exactly why it's slow?